# Calculating cost of selections in database queries

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out the theoretical cost of several queries:

Primary key on c

```
Select *
From W
Where W.c = “ccc”
```

Compound Primary key on a,b,c

```
Select *
From R
Where R.a = ‘aaa’ AND R.b = ‘bbb’ And R.c = ‘ccc’
```

What would the cost of reading the data be for these queries? I know that a full table scan (if W and R are not clustered) is the number of tuples T(R) or T(W). Does the cost for a query not vary based on the `WHERE` clauses? I'd assume that you wouldn't have to read all the data from the table for the relation but I have no idea how to compute it exactly.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question?

Comment: Kinda, I'm just wondering if the select has to do a full table scan or if it can take shortcuts and read less data before searching for the predicate in the where clause. If it's the latter, I'm looking for how much less it reads!